# How group cookie inside the cookie consent's banner marketing cookies with shopware 6 app development?

Tags: shopware6

I am wondering if there is a way to put your own cookie in the marketing section of the shop's consent banner. Currently I am declaring my cookie in the manifest.xml like so:

```
<cookies>
  <cookie>
     <cookie>mycookie_consent</cookie>
       <snippet-name>mycookie</snippet-name>
       <value>accepted</value>
  </cookie>
</cookies>
```

The result is an additional entry inside the consent banner, which has to be accepted explicitply.

How can I be sure that the cookie can be easily accepted, either with clicking on "accept all cookies" or be part of a predefined group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the cookie entry in a `<group>` if you use the same core snippet name it will be merged in the existing cookie group

```xml
<cookies>
  <group>
    <snippet-name>cookie.groupRequired</snippet-name>

    <cookie>
      <cookie>mycookie_consent</cookie>
        <snippet-name>mycookie</snippet-name>
        <value>accepted</value>
    </cookie>
  </group>
</cookies>
```

you can find that in the [manifest reference](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/manifest-reference).

Comment: Hi, thank you. But how do I know the snippet name? Isn't it a custom name given by the shop owner?

Comment: I'm not sure where your `marketing` cookie section comes from, it may be that the shop owner renamed the snippet from the core or that another plugin adds that section.

The core comes with the following groups: `cookie.groupRequired`, `cookie.groupStatistical`, `cookie.groupComfortFeatures`